# Get the size of my disks on several system

Tags: linux, text-processing, hard-disk, fdisk

**Edit:**
I have several machine and I need to get the total storage size of the main disk.
The problem I have is that on some machine my disk have the name `/dev/sda` or `/dev/md126p3`.
How could I reliably get the size of my disk on all those system.

Machine 1:

```
root@maximus:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md126p3     20G  3,6G   15G  20% /
/dev/md126p2   1008M   89M  868M  10% /boot
/dev/md126p1     99M  238K   99M   1% /boot/efi
```

Machine 2:

```
root@firefly:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        30G  2,8G   26G  10% /
/dev/sda2      1008M   61M  896M   7% /boot
/dev/sda1        20M  132K   20M   1% /boot/efi
```

Machine 3:

```
root@backup:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0        7,3T  297G  6,6T   5% /
/dev/md1        733M   57M  623M   9% /boot
```

Machine 4:

```
root@vmfarm1:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md126p3     18G  8,0G  9,3G  47% /
/dev/md126p2    190M   87M   90M  50% /boot
/dev/md126p1    119M  121K  119M   1% /boot/efi
```

Machine 5:

```
root@p12:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-1       6.3T  4.8T  1.3T  80% /
/dev/sda2       237M   60M  166M  27% /boot
```

Machine 6:

```
root@accountant:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                 20G  415M   19G   3% /
/dev/mapper/acc-root   20G  415M   19G   3% /
/dev/md0             1012M   70M  891M   8% /boot
/dev/mapper/acc-home   20G  313M   19G   2% /home
/dev/mapper/acc-opt    20G  6.2G   13G  33% /opt
/dev/mapper/acc-usr    20G  1.2G   18G   7% /usr
/dev/mapper/acc-var    20G  802M   18G   5% /var
/dev/mapper/acc-tmp    20G  172M   19G   1% /tmp
```

Machine 7:

```
root@pve:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0        95G   74G   16G  83% /
/dev/fuse        30M   16K   30M   1% /etc/pve
```

Machine 8:

```
root@barclay:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1p1      2.6T   77G  2.4T   4% /
/dev/md0        186M   36M  141M  21% /boot
```

**Old question:**

Using `fdisk -l` i am trying to get the full Sectors value.
Using Debian OS.
fdisk -l will show you alot of info. I am in need of figuring out a way to cut a specific word/number out of it.
Basically, i need the biggest "Sectors" count there is.
For my current machine.

```
 Device      Start         End     Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1    3072        6143        3072   1.5M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2    6144      506879      500736 244.5M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  506880 14064672767 14064165888   6.6T Linux filesystem
```

(This is also different on my other machines)

Then

```
 fdisk -l | grep Linux | tail -1
```

Gives me `/dev/sda3  506880 14064672767 14064165888   6.6T Linux filesystem`
Yet this is not the total that i need. I managed to cut this out on one of my machines, but i was not able to find a way to cut/grep out the "4th from the end"

On my test machine, i managed to this.

```
fdisk -l | grep Linux | cut -d " " -f3 | tail -1 | awk '{$1=$1/(1024^2); print $1;}' | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' | awk '{ print $1"GB" }'
```

Comment: This is a completly different question from original. I am not sure what you meant by **main disk**. the disk that hold `/`? what if / is part of a 4 disk volume group ? I'll Vote To Close as "too broad".

Comment: The whole disk or just the root partition/filesystem?

Comment: The Whole, but someone linked me a post from 2010. There was a  `cat /proc/partitions/  ` and it be doing what i need. Sadly, some machines have other drives like md also, so  yea

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the size of the disk you can take the value:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/size
```

To identify the main partition I would say you can do something like this :

```
 df | grep -E "\/$" | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed 's/[0-9]*//g'
```

This will give you the name of the disk mounted `/` in my case `/dev/sda`.
After up to you how you want to script it.

**Old answer**

In this case, I would simply use `/sys`:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/subsystem/sda3/size
```

which gives numbers of sectors and I would use :

```
cat /sys/block/sda/subsystem/sda3/start
```

to get the start sector number.

It would be way easier than parsing `fdisk` which is not always exactly the same. It would be easy to get those value with a simple pattern:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/subsystem/sda*/size
```

Comment: Actually this is Good. Any cue how i could probably add all the numbers up into one?

Comment: Edit: found this way cat /sys/block/sda/subsystem/sda*/size | paste -sd+ -|bc

Comment: I think using sys instead of parsing is way better that's why you cleary express your goal in a question and not only the technical problem your working on. Sometime better solution exists and you're heading in the wrong direction

Comment: What if my machine uses other /dev/sda's also? like vda or even something else

Comment: other sata disk will appear as `/dev/sdb` you could use `cat /sys/block/sd*/subsystem/sd*/size`

Comment: For an example, i have the following in use: ` md126p* sdc* sdb*  ` Probably afew more example could be given.

Comment: add df -h to your question and edit it to reflect your real question so we can answer in one time.

Comment: Added all 8 df -hs here.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
fdisk -l | awk '/Linux/ { s=$(NF-4) ;} END { print s}'
```

where

- `/Linux/` will select Linux line
- `{ s=$(NF-4) ;}` set 4th field from last (you might also use `$4` in this case.
- `END` at the end (no more input)
- `{ print s}` print it.

Edit:

- your `grep ..| cut .. | awk^n` code can be shortern to

  ```
  awk '/Linux/ { s=$4/(1024^2)  ;} END { printf "%d Gb\n",s}'
  ```
- sector are usualy 512 bytes, you may need to add another `/2` (divide by 2) to get Gb.

Comment: Thanks, will test it out. so far did what i needed on my test machine.

Comment: Oh, i did not know that. (1 sector is 512bytes) Therefor the way i was hoping to do is not the way to get full system disk space.

Comment: Will use this method on one of my machines :P thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

To get the highest *sector value* :

```
fdisk -l | awk '$6=="Linux" && v < $4{v=$4}END{print v}'
```

Comment: Thanks, this also helped helped me with my situation.

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing the block device to df you can also pass the mount point. actually that's the default behaviour

```
# df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        8191416 6002396   2088840  75% /
```

source: df manpage:

> df displays the amount of disk space available on the file system
>   containing each file name argument.